# New Laravel Project - Twitter Bootstrap - npm

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, heroku, npm

So, I just created a basic laravel project and deployed it to heroku. There were some things in the guide that were wrong and had to be corrected during that deployment so maybe I messed something up.

Anyway, I just want to run the standard npm run dev and compile the sass for bootstrap and yet I get a multitude of errors. Here is the first one ...

```
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --
progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-
mix/setup/webpack.config.js

events.js:141
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
at startup (node.js:139:18)
at node.js:968:3
```

Prior to this, I ran the standard ...

```
composer update
npm install
```

Any ideals. Frustrating that Laravel seems to come out of the box broken.

Comment: What are your node and npm versions? The error you've shown doesn't have anything to do with Laravel, but more so to do with your npm and node versions being out of date, I think.

Comment: Let me start by saying that Laravel does **not** come broken out of the box. I literally just made a fresh project, ran `npm install && npm run dev` and everything works fine. You must've messed something up with your setup. I suggest you give us more information. Firstly, which Laravel version did you install? Is this a fresh Laravel install or did you change anything?
 What versions of Node and NPM does your server have? Give us something to work with...

Comment: try updating your node and npm